# Codeigniter my form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I am using form_helper in CodeIgniter:

```
$current = $this->lang->mci_current();
$uri = 'contact';
$url = $this->lang->mci_make_uri($current, $uri);     // output "en/contact"

echo form_open($url);
```

**Question:**

how to modify form_helper to change it to default:

```
echo form_open('contact');
```

but with functionality I defined in previous code.

I am assuming, that I can **make my own form helper**
(`../application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php`)
there for **how to modify** it and **how to use** my own helper ?
<del>If I prefix helper with "my_" that means I override default form_helper? Do I need to extend default form_helper?</del>

This is what I managed to do:

*Note: I am new in MVC and OOP, learning with CodeIgniter*

**My try:**

```
if (!function_exists('form_open')) {

    function form_open($action = '', $attributes = '', $hidden = array()) {
        $CI = & get_instance();

        $current = $CI->lang->mci_current();
        $action = $CI->lang->mci_make_uri($current, $action);

        if ($attributes == '') {
            $attributes = 'method="post"';
        }

        // If an action is not a full URL then turn it into one
        if ($action && strpos($action, '://') === FALSE) {
            $action = $CI->config->site_url($action);
        }

        // If no action is provided then set to the current url
        $action OR $action = $CI->config->site_url($CI->uri->uri_string());

        $form = '<form action="' . $action . '"';

        $form .= _attributes_to_string($attributes, TRUE);

        $form .= '>';

        // Add CSRF field if enabled, but leave it out for GET requests and requests to external websites   
        if ($CI->config->item('csrf_protection') === TRUE AND !(strpos($action, $CI->config->base_url()) === FALSE OR strpos($form, 'method="get"'))) {
            $hidden[$CI->security->get_csrf_token_name()] = $CI->security->get_csrf_hash();
        }

        if (is_array($hidden) AND count($hidden) > 0) {
            $form .= sprintf("<div style=\"display:none\">%s</div>", form_hidden($hidden));
        }

        return $form;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Helpers` in `CI` are not `class(es)`. They are simply functions. Make your own helper and save them in `application/helpers`. Load the helpers as usual

```
$this->load->helper('helperName'); #your file name should be helperName_helper.php
```

If you want to extend the default helper(s) just append `MY_` with the default helper name and save in the `application/helpers` as you said. This will `add / override` the default functions.

Comment: So as I assumed my helper should be named `MY_form_helper.php` located in `application/helpers/`. Is there difference when I use `my_` instead of `MY_` ?

Comment: **Yes**, as per the documentation, you should use `MY_`. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/helpers.html